# Generación de nuget por consola

Tags: nuget

Estoy intentado generar paquetes nuget por comando, pero me arroja un error. Os pongo en situación.

He generado el fichero .nuspec con el comando

```
nuget spec
```

La estructura del fichero es la siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Ahora me gustaría generarlo en base a las etiquetas dinámicas ($id$), para eso, uso el siguiente comando.

```
nuget pack "nompre.proyecto.csproj" -Version 6.6.6 -Properties Configuration=release;Id="MiPaquete.Sample";Description="MyDescription";Authors="MeMeMeMeToo";Summary="MySummary";ReleaseNotes="MyChanges";Owners="MyCompany";
```

Me arroja los siguientes errores

> *Authors is required*.
>
> *Description is required*.

La verdad que no entiendo porque, dado que las etiquetas están y el comando, por lo que he visto se separa por puntos y comas.

La idea es poder hacer dinámico todo el .nuspec, con etiquetas, imágenes para cada nuget, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si alguna ves le pasa alguien, la solucion es escapar las dobles comillas en el comando y ya pasa bien los parametros al fichero nuspec y genera todo correctamente.

```
nuget pack "nompre.proyecto.csproj" -Version 6.6.6 -Properties "Configuration=release;Id="MiPaquete.Sample";Description=""My Description"";Authors="MeMeMeMeToo";Summary="MySummary";ReleaseNotes="MyChanges";Owners=""My Company"""
```

***Cuidado a las dobles comillas en las que contienen espacios***